# Turning a regular expression into a DFA

Tags: finite-automata

i'm studying for an exam i'll have soon and i don't understand how to draw a DFA for a regular expression, i asked my professor by mail but he doesn't asnwer...
In the courses available on my college's website there is no step by step exemple
Here is the expression i'm trying to convert b(a∗dc)∗

Thank you for the help !

edit i've done this but i'm not sure:

[image: i tried]

Comment: Your attempt doesn't seem to match the regular expression you asked about. Maybe you pasted another DFA for an unrelated expression instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively break down your regular expression into elementary sub-expressions.

In you case you can write your expression $E=b(a^*dc)^*$ as the concatenation of $b$ with $(a^*dc)^*$.
In turn $(a^*dc)^*$ is the Kleene closure of  $a^*dc$ which can be broken down as $a^*$ and $dc$.  Finally $a^*$ is the Kleene closure of $a$.

You can construct your NFA from bottom up:
Design a DFA for $a$ (which is trivial).

Now transform it into a NFA for $a^*$ (add an $\epsilon$-transition from the final state to the initial state $x$, then add a new initial state $x'$ and add an $\epsilon$-transition from $x'$ to $x$).

Design a DFA for dc (also trivial).

Concatenate the NFA for $a^*$ with the DFA for $dc$ to obtain a NFA for $a^*dc$.

Transform the NFA for $a^*dc$ into a NFA for $(a^*dc)^*$.

Design a DFA for $b$ (again, trivial).

Concatenate the DFA for $b$ with the NFA for $a^*dc$ to obtain a NFA for $b(a^*dc)^*$.

Transform the resulting NFA to a DFA using standard techniques.

[image: dfa]

Comment: That makes a lot more of sense now ! Thank you for your help !